# Set ListView height after click on button inside custom adapter (android)

Tags: android

I have a problem with the Custom Adapter for a list view. I made a custom layout with a TextView and a Button. I want that when the button is clicked, after removing item from the list, the list's height is changed according to the number of items on the list. 
The problem is, the method I found to do that requests a list view with a adapter, so I can't call it INSIDE the custom adapter.
How can I set the height of the listview inside the custom adapter?

MyCustomAdapter.java:

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {
private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
private Context context;
private ListView lista;


public MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> list, Context context) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int pos) {
    return list.get(pos);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int pos) {
    return 0;
    //just return 0 if your list items do not have an Id variable.
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, null);
    }

    TextView listItemText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.item);
    listItemText.setText(list.get(position));

    Button btnExcluir = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnExcluir);

    btnExcluir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            list.remove(position); 
            notifyDataSetChanged();

    //HERE I want to change ListView's height
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Function to set ListView's height:

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null)
        return;

    int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    int totalHeight = 0;
    View view = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);
        if (i == 0)
            view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        view.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

custom_row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnExcluir"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnExcluir"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnExcluir"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_btnexcluir"
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    android:minWidth="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="87dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="87dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the constructor like this ,

```
  public MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> list, Context context, ListView lista) {
            this.list = list;
            this.context = context;
            this.lista = lista;
        }
```

and you can call it inside your adapter class.

Comment: @MarianaBittencourt could you please accept the answer.